# VBScript XML indentation with CDATA

Tags: xml, vbscript, indentation

I would like to generate a XML file from VBScript. I found `Microsoft.XMLDOM` but it seems this class does not know how to indent my output file. I tried to use MSXML2 to reindent my xml but when I use it my CDATA sections vanished...

VBScript:

```
set xml = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
set encoding = xml.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'")
xml.insertBefore encoding, xml.childNodes.Item(0)
set foo = xml.createElement("foo")
foo.setAttribute "foobar", "42"

set bar = xml.createElement("bar")
set cdata = xml.createCDATASection("Hello World!")
bar.appendChild cdata
foo.appendChild bar
xml.appendChild(foo)

' XML okay but ugly because no indentation
xml.save("a.xml")

' XML pretty but the 'cdata' sections vanished...
xmlSave xml, "b.xml"

function xmlSave(xml, filename)
    set rdr = CreateObject("MSXML2.SAXXMLReader")
    set wrt = CreateObject("MSXML2.MXXMLWriter")
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.STREAM")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Charset = "ISO-8859-1"

    wrt.indent = True
    wrt.encoding = "ISO-8859-1"
    wrt.output = oStream
    Set rdr.contentHandler = wrt
    Set rdr.errorHandler = wrt

    rdr.Parse xml
    wrt.flush

    oStream.SaveToFile filename, 2
end function
```

Output:

```
$ cscript //nologo test.vbs && cat a.xml && echo -e "------" && cat b.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<foo foobar="42"><bar><![CDATA[Hello World!]]></bar></foo>
------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<foo foobar="42">
        <bar>Hello World!</bar>
</foo>
```

How can I easily get a nice indented XML with XMLDOM without loosing my CDATA sections ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something that works...

```
Function ParseAndSave(filePath, xmlDoc)
    set xmlWriter = CreateObject("MSXML2.MXXMLWriter")
    set xmlReader = CreateObject("MSXML2.SAXXMLReader")
    Set xmlStream = CreateObject("ADODB.STREAM")
    xmlStream.Open
    xmlStream.Charset = "ISO-8859-1"

    xmlWriter.output = xmlStream
    xmlWriter.indent = True
    xmlWriter.standalone = True
    xmlWriter.encoding = "ISO-8859-1"

    Set xmlReader.contentHandler = xmlWriter
    Set xmlReader.DTDHandler = xmlWriter
    Set xmlReader.errorHandler = xmlWriter
    xmlReader.putProperty "http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler", xmlWriter
    xmlReader.putProperty "http://xml.org/sax/properties/declaration-handler", xmlWriter

    xmlReader.parse xmlDoc
    xmlWriter.flush

    xmlStream.SaveToFile filePath, 2

    xmlStream.Close
    Set xmlStream = Nothing
    Set xmlWriter = Nothing
    Set xmlReader = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

The first misconception I see in your code is the assumption that `<?xml ...?>` is a processing instruction. This is not the case. It is the *XML declaration*. You cannot produce it with `createProcessingInstruction()`. Trying will result in a broken output document.

The next misconception is that XML must look neat. Or that you need CDATA for anything.

*Those two points might be somewhat controversial, but in general neither neat-looking XML nor CDATA fulfill any technical purpose. If your OCD permits it, get over them.*

The third misconception is that "indent" was anything other than text nodes that contain only whitespace. XML retains your data, and text nodes (whitespace or not) *are* data. If you don't add any text nodes that only contain line breaks and spaces/tabs, then there won't be any in the output.

In short: If you want indented nodes, you must add the indentation manually. This process is commonly called "pretty-printing".

You can pretty-print a document with a recursive function like this one *(getting this "right" it trickier than one might think, I cannot guarantee the output is exactly how you would do it)*:

```vb
' public function, pass a DOMDocument to it. modifies that document in-place.
Sub IndentDocument(doc, indentStr)
  IndentNode doc.DocumentElement, Left(indentStr, 1), Len(indentStr), 0
End Sub

' --------------------------------------------------------------------------
' helper functions, don't call directly...    
Sub IndentNode(node, indentChar, perLevel, level)
  Dim parent, child, doc

  If node.NodeType = 9 Then
    IndentNode node.DocumentElement, indentChar, perLevel, level
  ElseIf CanIndent(node) Then
    IndentRemove node
    Set doc = node.OwnerDocument
    If Not node Is doc.DocumentElement Then
      Set parent = node.ParentNode
      If node Is parent.FirstChild Or CanIndent(node.PreviousSibling) Then
        parent.InsertBefore doc.createTextNode(vbLf & String(level * perLevel, indentChar)), node
      End If
      If node Is parent.LastChild Then
        parent.InsertBefore doc.createTextNode(vbLf & String((level - 1) * perLevel, indentChar)), Nothing
      End If
    End If
    If node.ChildNodes.Length > 0 Then
      For Each child In node.ChildNodes
        IndentNode child, indentChar, perLevel, level + 1
      Next
    End If
  End If
End Sub

Function CanIndent(node)
  If node Is Nothing Then
    CanIndent = False
  Else
    CanIndent = node.NodeType = 1 Or node.NodeType = 8
  End If
End Function

Sub IndentRemove(node)
  Dim child, i

  For i = node.ChildNodes.Length To 1 Step -1
    Set child = node.ChildNodes(i - 1)
    If child.NodeType = 3 And Trim(Replace(Replace(child.Text, vbCr, ""), vbLf, "")) = "" Then
      node.RemoveChild child
    End If
    Set child = Nothing
  Next
End Sub
```

Usage

```vb
Set doc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

' load skeleton XML document with pre-defined output encoding
doc.LoadXML "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""ISO-8859-1""?><foo />"


' ... now create all kinds of nodes here ...


' indent document with two spaces and save
IndentDocument doc, "  "
doc.Save "foo.xml"
```

On a general note: Consider really closely if you want to use ISO-8859-1 for any new files you create. UTF-8 is the way to go these days, you should not use legacy file encodings for anything new anymore. Especially not in XML, since *all* XML parsers understand UTF-8.