# VB script XML make pretty

Tags: vbscript

I have searched and read other questions that have answers but they all assume the XML is already saved as a file. This is what I am looking for [Format XML string in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25067839/format-xml-string-in-vbscript) . But it uses Server to create the XML it may be that I do not understand "Server" When I try the below code it tells me the server object does not exist. This is not a web server application.

```
Dim objXSL : Set objXSL = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
objXSL.loadXML  "<xsl:stylesheet version=""1.0"" xmlns:xsl=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"">" & _
                "<xsl:output method=""xml"" indent=""yes""/>" & _
                "<xsl:template match=""/"">" & _
                "<xsl:copy-of select="".""/>" & _
                "</xsl:template>" & _
                "</xsl:stylesheet>"
```

I am using VBS to create an XML file. The file creation works and I get what I expect but it is created on one long line. Even though it works to help with debugging and confirming the correct data is being output I would like to have the file formatted with indents.

is there a quick way to get the formatted indents? I have found some solutions but they all appear to be server applications. My script is running inside of a VB.net using msscript.ocx.

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format XML string in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25067839/format-xml-string-in-vbscript)

Comment: `Server.CreateObject()` is what you'd use in an ASP page. [CreateObject()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa220083(v=office.11)) is the equivalent in VBScript.